# Can a single company really not use QB API?...Semi Rant

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

We need to integrate our custom in house applications with quickbooks. When I saw the QB REST API and the IPP I was like "Yay!!! Finally Qb offered us something useful!".

It was a happy moment.....

Then I read this in the FAQ

> I want to integrate my custom (non-SaaS, single-tenant) solution with QuickBooks API. Can I do this?
>   Not today, but we are considering it.

What? Why?

were paying customers, we have integration problems....largely caused by YOU intuit!

You already built it...I assume it works...so there's no effort whatsoever on your part!

So now you offer an API on a silver platter....but...oh wait....you can't use it.

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Somebody tell me that I'm simply misunderstanding this....

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is correct. IPP Intuit Anywhere is the new platform only for SaaS applications.

Intuit still provides the traditional QBSDK SDK v12, which is useful if you are creating a custom integration for one company, or focused entirely on desktop scenarios only.
QBSDK Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb

Comment: The traditional SDK is junk for us...We do most of our business online. Our in-house CRM runs on Rails, that REST API is exactly what we need. What good is a windows SDK gonna be on Linux/Rails?

Comment: You can use the Web Connector, or write a web-based bridge using the SDK. I imagine that IPP will be available someday for all apps, but in the meantime the SDK/Web Connector *can* do what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a good option for you but we have created a pretty slick sync with QuickBooks using the SDK for the Method Integration platform. You can use our API with the sync engine to do what you need. You'll need a Method account though which is $40.00 per month.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a lot of integration with QB, and prefer to use the RSSBus ADO.NET provider. It is infinitely easier than using Intuit's SDK, and has great documentation, such as - http://cdn.rssbus.com/help/RQ4/ado/pg_desktoptable-purchaseorders.htm. It works with the Desktop version and QB online.

I am not affiliated with them at all, just a happy customer!