# Is it possible to connect my app to my QBO account using the intuit development server indefinitely?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I originally posted this question as an 'answer' to:
[Can a single company really not use QB API?...Semi Rant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730617/can-a-single-company-really-not-use-qb-api-semi-rant/18770647#18770647)

but am reposting, because it is a question.

The original poster and I face a similar problem wanting to use the QBO API for an application designed for a single company. What would be the disadvantage of connecting my app to my QBO account using the intuit development server indefinitely, i.e., never take my app through the production qualification process?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is possible but then you can use at max 10 developer connections.
As we already mentioned we do not not support custom integrations at this time.
Even we wouldn’t recommend moving you to production as it would cost us $1k per year to security review it, and we would only recover about $60 per year in connection fees.

So, the disadvantage for you will be in terms of number of connections, limited support and your app vulnerability since it has not gone through the security review process. 
Please read the policy docs mentioned here:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0005_introduction_to_quickbooksapi/z_developer_policies_and_guidelines

Edit for the question asked:
When you login into developer.intuit.com, Go to Manage My Apps, then click your app.
You will see the number of connections for that app under Test connections.
It refers to the numbers of company files your app is associated with or has been authorized to access data.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, Nimisha.  I need clarification on what a 'developer connection' is.  In trying to negotiate the best way to solve my problem, my Manage My Apps screen has 4 apps.  One unstaged, two staged (integrated with QBooks API), one QBOE production (access through SDK), all connected to the same QBooks account.  Yesterday, I got message: "staged instances has exceeded 10 please contact … IA development … ", which in my frustration, I failed to save.  But today, I am still able to connect to my account.

So, could you please tell me, technically, what a 'developer connection' means.  Thanks.

Comment: Please see the edit above.If all your 10 connections are used, then you can create and use another app or disconnect all connections from the button and then use 10 new connections for the same app.